# Trouble installing libunwind-headers via macports

Tags: gcc, macports

**In an effort to**

```
sudo port install gcc47
```

**It appears that i am missing**

- cctools
- ld64
- libunwind-headers

**where both**

- cctools
- ld64

**depend on**

- libunwind-headers

**When trying to**

```
sudo port install libunwind-headers
```

**I get:**

```
--->  Building libunwind-headers
Error: org.macports.build for port libunwind-headers returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port libunwind-headers for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port libunwind-headers failed
```

The log file says:

```
25 :info:build Command failed: cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libunwind-headers    /libunwind-headers/work/libunwind-30" && /usr/bin/xcodebuild  -target "libunwind-ld" -configuration Deployment build OBJROOT=build/ SYMROOT=build/ MACOSX_DEPLO    YMENT_TARGET=10.8 ARCHS= SDKROOT="" GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
 26 :info:build Exit code: 69
 27 :error:build org.macports.build for port libunwind-headers returned: command execution failed
 28 :debug:build Error code: NONE
 29 :debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
 30     while executing
 31 "$procedure $targetname"
 32 :info:build Warning: targets not executed for libunwind-headers: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
 33 :notice:build Please see the log file for port libunwind-headers for details:
 34     /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/main.log
```

**How should i proceed with this please?**

Comment: What OS / Xcode version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to accept Apple's license agreement before attempting to install `libunwind-headers`

```
sudo xcodebuild -license agree
```

Comment: remarkable! Hope it's the last xcode-related bad joke I'm stumbling upon since upgrading my OS...