# Error while extracting libunwind-headers on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macports, osx-mavericks

I'm having a difficult time upgrading the **libunwind-headers** port in macports. I've already looked into the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888222/trouble-installing-libunwind-headers-via-macports) on this:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license agree
```

This did not fix the problem.

Here's my terminal output:

```
new-host-2 [~] % sudo port upgrade outdated
--->  Extracting libunwind-headers
Error: org.macports.extract for port libunwind-headers returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port libunwind-headers for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/main.log
Error: Problem while installing libunwind-headers
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

Here's my log file:

```
version:1
:debug:main libunwind-headers has no conflicts
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (libunwind-headers)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (libunwind-headers)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (libunwind-headers)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (libunwind-headers)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:extract extract phase started at Wed Nov  6 12:42:26 EST 2013
:notice:extract --->  Extracting libunwind-headers
:debug:extract Executing org.macports.extract (libunwind-headers) 
:info:extract --->  Extracting libunwind-35.1.tar.gz
:debug:extract setting option extract.args to '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libunwind-headers/libunwind-35.1.tar.gz'
:debug:extract Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include'   CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.mac ports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'  LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
:debug:extract Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libunwind-headers/libunwind-35.1.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf -'
:debug:extract Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libunwind-headers/libunwind-35.1.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
:info:extract gzip: error writing to output: Broken pipe
:info:extract gzip: /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libunwind-headers/libunwind-35.1.tar.gz: uncompress failed
:info:extract Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/libunwind-headers/libunwind-35.1.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract Exit code: 127
:error:extract org.macports.extract for port libunwind-headers returned: command execution failed
:debug:extract Error code: NONE
:debug:extract Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:extract Warning: targets not executed for libunwind-headers: org.macports.activate org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:extract Please see the log file for port libunwind-headers for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_libunwind-headers/libunwind-headers/main.log
```

Does this seem like a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly? I've also tried cleaning it, and uninstalling/re-installing it.

Selfupdating also did not return any errors.

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
```

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry I forgot to add it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's waaaaay late on this, but for anybody getting here like I did:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/tar /usr/bin/gnutar`

Mavericks apparently changed the file name of tar.

Comment: BTW, yes I'm aware that MacPorts discourages this.  https://trac.macports.org/wiki/MavericksProblems  I don't care.  It works far easier than the actual instructions.